# How to keep defined date-time format when binding date-time vector with numeric value vector?

Tags: r

I've converted a character vector to a date-time vector, however when I attempt to bind this new vector of date-times to a numeric value vector, it converts the date-time vector to numbers.

```
numbers <- c(1:5)
character.datetimes <- as.character(c("2019-05-01 17:21:03.500", "2019-05-01 17:21:13.531", "2019-05-01 17:21:22.673", "2019-05-01 17:21:23.546", "2019-05-01 17:21:32.657"))
corrected.datetimes <- as.POSIXct(datetimes, format = "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%OS")
output <- cbind(corrected.datetimes, numbers)
```

which gives:

1556756464, 1556756474, 1556756483, 1556756484, 1556756493 respectively for the datetimes instead of the proper format. why?

I've tried using strptime in various arrangements but it hasn't yielded the desired result. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you check `class(output)` it is a matrix and it can hold data of only one type hence, it coerces `datetimes` to number. It would be fixed if you do `output <- data.frame(corrected.datetimes, numbers)` instead.

Comment: this answers my question to g. grothendieck below. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`cbind` is trying to create a matrix and a matrix can only have values of one type.

You could use any of these to create a data frame, zoo series or xts series:

```
data.frame(corrected.datetimes, numbers)

library(zoo)
zoo(numbers, corrected.datetimes)

library(xts)
xts(numbers, corrected.datetimes)
```

Comment: ah, thank you. could a data single-column dataframe be made using this vector first, and then the numeric column be appended to it?

Comment: It can be done in stages like this: `DF <- data.frame(numbers); DF$corrected.datetimes <- corrected.datetimes`